# How to detect that a user click on "open" inside the play store to launch my app?

Tags: android, google-play

How to detect that a user clicks on the button "open" inside the play store to launch my app (when the app is already installed) instead of launching directly the app by tapping its icon inside android main screen?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use firebase, it is an example

```
<body>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/6.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>
```

The link is the next [https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=es-419][1]

[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=es-419, this link is showing how implement